# Using UTF-8 query not working in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8

I have this user_model.java below:

```
public class User_Model implements Serializable {


 @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ColumnTransformer(
            read="AES_DECRYPT(username, 'Hf7p4u6e') USING utf8))",
            write="AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'Hf7p4u6e')")
```

The above code is working when I remove `USING utf8)` but when I put it again I get this error

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.USING user_mo0_.UTF-8)`.

I don't want to remove the `utf8` because I used it for korean language.

I also put a utf8 setting in my hibernate.xml

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

But still, it's not work at all.How can I make my query work? any help

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Maybe you ned to use 'USING utf8' with CONVERT function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html)

  CONVERT(_latin1 AES_DECRYPT(username, 'Hf7p4u6e') USING utf8)
- utf8 has nothing to do with your already created tables if they are not in UTF-8. This only forces newly created tables to use UTF-8. Existing tables remain as they are.

Comment: I already used the convert function but the error still the same

Comment: It's obvious that this is a syntax problem. Documentation says you need to specify original encoding:  SELECT CONVERT(_latin1'Müller' USING utf8); Maybe you need to add it to your syntax. I'l ledit my answer.

Comment: Try to print the query and see what is wrong. Use     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

Comment: I have seen the printed query `select message_mo0_.id as id0_, AES_DECRYPT(message_mo0_.userName, 'Hf7p4u6e') using UTF-8 as userName_, from users message_mo0_`. There still a error

Comment: There is no CONVERT( function call. It should be:  select message_mo0_.id as id0_, CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT(message_mo0_.userName, 'Hf7p4u6e') using UTF-8) as userName_, from users message_mo0_  Check the way you define your read= transformation.  It should look lile read="CONVERT (AES_DECRYPT(username, 'Hf7p4u6e') USING utf8)",

Comment: Before I already tried to put a CONVERT. Like this `select message_mo0_.id as id0_, CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(message_mo0_.createdBy, 'Hf7p4u6e') message_mo0_.USING message_mo0_.utf8) as userName_, from users message_mo0_.`

Comment: The error I get is `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'message_mo0_.USING message_mo0_.utf8) as userName_`

Comment: Well the problem is that Hibernate is ataching 'message_mo0_.' (table alias in the query) to several strings in CONVERT function: message_mo0_.USING  and message_mo0_.utf8. Maybe there is a way to tell Hiberante not to do it marking  'USING utf8'  as a literal.

Comment: There should not be a "." before "USING"; where is it coming from?

Comment: @RickJames I do not know where is it coming from. I tried to add a double quotes in my query but still doesn't work.